# Why does my cat have an upset stomach?

Tags: cats, diet

I typically feed my cat a boiled fish fillet, "Hoki" ... (http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-hoki.htm ) we switched him to this after a one-week bout of diarrhea one month ago... it healed it within 2 days. We also have a bowl of dry food going for him at all times but I barely see him eat it.

This week we ran out of the Hoki and it was over a day before I could get back to the store to get some, so was feeding my cat canned tuna in the meantime. When I reached the store I discovered they were out of it, so settled for mackerel pieces instead... I boiled these up last night, removed all the bones, and tested him on a handful of it. He loved it initially, enthusiastically chomping away... and then I was shocked to see him walk away from it leaving 50% of it untouched.

After 15minutes he had a burst of diarrhea in his litter-box. I threw the rest of the mackerel away.  Half an hour later he had another burst, after which he was licking/cleaning his genetalia incessantly, and hissing at me if I tried to go near him (he wasn't like this with his previous diarrhea attack a month ago). I went to bed and woke up several times in the night to see him sitting in my bedroom, yet again cleaning his private parts each time.

This morning I inspected the house for any more diarrhea bursts, I could only find what looked like some streaking on the rug, but not sure how that would come about if he was cleaning himself so diligently. Was it a case of 'leakage' that he was trying to deal with, and what happened on the rug was him momentarily giving up on cleaning it away?

There was also a small pool of vomit with  large chunk of undigested mackerel in it. This morning he was still cleaning himself, and hissed at me again when I tried to go near him. He also refused to eat any tuna and curled up in the dining room to sleep at a time that he does not usually go to sleep. I noticed he was also working his mouth a lot, licking his chops as if he had just had a large meal. I did manage to pick him up for a while to hold him up to some running water as I was afraid he wasn't being proactive with his water bowl. He drank a lot of the running water.

He woke up again when he heard me going outside to put out the trash and came out to play in the garden momentarily... he seemed his old self for a bit, but is back inside curled up asleep again.

Do you think it was the mackeral that is causing this, or the 1.5 days of canned tuna?

Comment: The condition you describe could be indicative of an urgent or emergency health issue, please contact your vet for direction on how soon your pet needs to be seen. If someone knowledgeable in first aid is available, they may be able to write an answer, but you should not wait.

Comment: Thanks @Zaralynda , 30mins after I posted this, he was back to his old self, crying for tuna, gobbling it down, and playing around the house. He has not had any diarrhea since, so it was definitely the mackerel. I spoke to a butcher about it and they think it may have been going off.